# Port not opening

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, port, port-forwarding, ubuntu-16.04

I have a dedicated OVH server and I am trying to open port 30110 for outgoing TCP and port 30120 UCP/TCP for incoming and outgoing. I am trying to install a server through fivem.net. I tried to hire someone to take a look and they weren't able to figure it out. They followed the same steps they took on my server on their own VPS and was able to get it installed there.

30110 seems to be working. I have tested using the command

```
telnet portquiz.net 30110
```

For 30120 TCP I have tested here: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and it says port is closed. I have other ports open that do work.

I have contacted OVH, but they only help when it is a hardware related issue. They say it is not hardware or anything on their end. I have a gaming firewall and a mitigation firewall, they are basically the same thing. They are both disabled and not running.

My iptables rules are all set to allowed. My ufw is set to disabled, but I have also allowed the ports for when I turn it on. I have been messing around with this for about a week with no luck.

Here are some of the outputs.

```
ufw status verbose
```

[image]

```
iptables -L
```

[image]

```
netstat -tulpn
```

[image]

I am at a loss on what to do next. Is there another package that can control ports and interfere with ufw or iptables?

Comment: works for me `Connection to portquiz.net port 30110 [tcp/*] succeeded!`

Comment: TCP port 30120 is open and working. It seems to be a server of some sort.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that is working for me too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not sure what you mean by it seems to be a server of some sort.

Comment: I guess it's some kind of game server. I tried to send it an HTTP request but it just responded 400 Bad request. But anyway, whatever problem you were having, you no longer appear to be having it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, it is a game server. I am still having the same problem. I was always able to send out data from 30110. The problem is port 30120 isn't opening

Comment: You should describe the problem more clearly, then. As far as I can tell, port 30120 is open.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried to give as much info as possible and I guess my problem got lost in all the extra stuff. Do you have a way I can contact you directly about this? I tried to hire someone to fix this, but they weren't able to figure it out.

Comment: First, you should go check to see if you are actually having this problem still. Again, the port you say is not open is actually open.